# How to visualize variations clearly?

Tags: analysis, annotation, visualization

So,I'm reading some annotated games and analyzing them in some app.I feel too lazy to make separate moves for the variations give and tend to do them in my head,but i find it difficult to do after say 5 moves(each).Does it comes with practice or   how to improve that?

Comment: In the top left hand corner of the page next to where it says "StackExchange" there is a little magnifying glass next to "Search on Chess". Try typing "Visualization" in there, press "Enter" and you will see lots of other questions on visualization just like this one. Some of them have even been closed as duplicates! Just like this one. Before you write a question please use the Search function to see if your question has already been asked.